# MySql - Having issues with count and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, inner-join

Can someone please help me finding where the mistake is? I'm trying to count some rows from multiple tables and group them by 'ven_codigo', but I'm getting the total count instead of the count per each table.

These are the results I'm getting.

Counting propostas
[image: Counting propostas]

Counting pedidos
[image: Counting pedidos]

Counting propostas and pedidos
[image: Counting propostas and pedidos]

```
select v.ven_codigo, 
        /*count(a.ven_codigo) as atividades_realizadas, v.ven_meta_atividades, 
        count(ha.usu_codigo) as historico_atividades,
        count(c.cli_codigo) as clientes_cadastrados,*/
        count(p.ven_codigo) as propostas_realizadas,  v.ven_meta_propostas,
        count(pv.ven_codigo) as pedidos_realizados
    from vendedor v
    inner join comp_usuario_vendedor cuv on cuv.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo
    inner join usuario u on u.usu_codigo = cuv.usu_codigo
    /*inner join atividade a on a.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo
    inner join historico_atividade ha on ha.usu_codigo = u.usu_codigo
    inner join clientes c on c.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo*/
    inner join proposta p on p.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo
    inner join pedido_venda pv on pv.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo

    where v.ven_codigo >= 1 and v.ven_codigo <= 3
        /*and a.ati_data_emissao > '2016-01-01'*/
    group by v.ven_codigo, /*a.ven_codigo, ha.usu_codigo, c.cli_codigo,*/ 
p.ven_codigo, pv.ven_codigo;
```

Ps: I commented out part of the code, because how I'm something wrong, it's taking way too long to run the whole query.

Comment: See if this is helpful.. [Count rows with inner joined tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/110850/124935)

Comment: Can you run `explain` on these queries and look where cardinality of a join is very high, or a full scan is attempted?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena it did. Thanks. I did all my counting using subqueries.

Comment: I don't see the recommended subqueries, nor the `EXPLAINs`.  (Yet.)

Comment: @RickJames oops, sorry. When I posted the comment I wasn't using the pc I had mysql in. I just can't get EXPLAIN to give me those nice tables, so that's why I'm just posting the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DhruvSaxena's link helped me get to this final query, using subqueries to do the counting. Results below.

```
select v.ven_codigo,
    (select count(a.ven_codigo) 
        from atividade a  
        where a.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo 
            and a.ati_data_emissao > '2016-01-01'
        group by a.ven_codigo) as atividades_realizadas, v.ven_meta_atividades, 

      (select count(ha.usu_codigo)
        from historico_atividade ha
        inner join usuario u on u.usu_codigo = ha.usu_codigo
        inner join comp_usuario_vendedor cuv on cuv.usu_codigo = u.usu_codigo
        where cuv.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo
        group by v.ven_codigo) as  historico_atividades,

    (select count(c.cli_codigo) 
        from clientes c 
        where c.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo 
        group by c.ven_codigo) as clientes_cadastrados,

    (select count(p.ven_codigo) 
        from proposta p 
        where p.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo 
        group by p.ven_codigo) as propostas_realizadas,  v.ven_meta_propostas,

    (select count(pv.ven_codigo) 
        from pedido_venda pv 
        where pv.ven_codigo = v.ven_codigo 
        group by pv.ven_codigo) as pedidos_realizados

from vendedor v
where v.ven_codigo >= 1 and v.ven_codigo <= 3
group by v.ven_codigo;
```

[image]